# Sine wave PWM: which is better analog or digital?

Tags: oscillator, inverter, stability, sine

I'm designing a low power DC/AC sinewave inverter and I have 2 choices for the pulse width modulation :

1. Generating SPWM using an AVR microcontroller timers/counters.
2. Generating the waveform using a bubba oscillator with square wave.

I know that the 4-section bubba oscillator has good stability because it has high rate of change of phase with frequency but I don't know if it's suitable for 50 Hz operation  I think it's better at lower frequencies(or not?))

Comment: what's a bubba oscillator? What's SPWM (I know what PWM is). What are your other requirements (small size, high accuracy, able to go 0-100%, low cost, purchased parts only?)

Comment: Stability (at 50 hz) and low cost are the most important requirements for now.

Comment: @Neil_UK SPWM is simply sine pwm (Sorry i thought it's a common expression :D ) , and here's a good pdf about bubba oscillator : http://www.hscott.net/bubba.pdf

I acutally got the basic knowledgement from "opamps for every one" from texas instruments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> i don't know if it's suitable for 50 hz operation

A bubba oscillator is just a phase shift oscillator and so can be made to work at any frequency within reason. It uses op-amps to provide low-loading of the phase shift circuits so that the frequency of operation is more mathematically predictable. However it's very wasteful in its use of op-amps.

Like the Wien Bridge oscillator there is no natural amplitude stabilization so you find that the gain has to be dynamically controlled so, when you say: -

> I know that the 4-section bubba oscillator has good stability

This isn't exactly true because it trades distortion for amplitude stability.

If you want a decent sine wave oscillator I would consider making one that has a tight bandwidth (high Q) filter and in-built amplitude control like this one from Elliot Sound Products: -

[image]

Stolen from [this](https://sound-au.com/articles/sinewave.htm) page.

Comment: I got this idea that it has good stability from "opamps for everyone" from texas instruments so i trusted them :/ . 

Anyway great answer as always and thank you for the page, it's very informative.